# why it does not work the symbol # in call intent in andriod studio

Tags: android

When I want to add the symbol # in dialing call intent. It does not work in the physical app.How can I add the symbol # to dialing call to My App

Comment: what do you mean by ''physical app'' ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String hash = Uri.encode("#");
```

then put it in your call string:

Example:

```
 String ussdCode = "*100*2" + hash;
 startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel: " + ussdCode)));
```